# How do I make a program which can be used as an argument / exec in Terminal (OSX)?

Tags: macos, terminal

Certain programs you install on your comp become executable from terminal when you install them (node, python, etc.) How do you enable your executable to become a command line argument?

Excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure your program (or command line tool) is installed in a directory that is found by your "`$PATH`" environment variable.

The [SuperUser site](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) has a number of questions that show you how to modify $PATH so whatever tool you want to "install" can be easily run from the Terminal command line.